# A Menu that triggers purely on hover in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, menu, javafx-8

I have looked at a few JavaFX classes related to menu, but I could not find what I want. I want to implement something that works like a `MenuBar`, except that I want it to open its menu on hover, not on click. While I can definitely build something from scratch on my own, it would be a waste of time if there is already something that allows me to do something similar to that. Anyone knows how do I do that?

Comment: Use a custom `MenuBar` and change its listeners?

Comment: Check out [`ControlsFX`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is possible to make it if you use the `lookup()`. You can easily take the container holding the Menus and then apply on them the `setOnMouseEntered()` or `setOnMouseExited()` to catch mouse events on each Menu.

Here is an example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        Menu editMenu = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem fileMenuItem1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
        MenuItem fileMenuItem2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");
        MenuItem fileMenuItem3 = new MenuItem("Item 3");
        editMenu.getItems().addAll(fileMenuItem1, fileMenuItem2, fileMenuItem3);

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("Edit");
        MenuItem fileMenu1 = new MenuItem("Item 1");
        MenuItem fileMenu2 = new MenuItem("Item 2");
        MenuItem fileMenu3 = new MenuItem("Item 3");
        fileMenu.getItems().addAll(fileMenu1, fileMenu2, fileMenu3);

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(editMenu, fileMenu);

        mainPane.setTop(menuBar);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 300, 300);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // Find menubar HBox holding the menus
        HBox container = (HBox) menuBar.lookup("HBox");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < container.getChildren().size() ; i++) {
            Node parentNode = container.getChildren().get(i);
            Menu menu = menuBar.getMenus().get(i);

            parentNode.setOnMouseMoved(e->{
                menu.show();
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

You might wonder why i use the `setOnMouseMoved` instead of `setOnMouseEntered`. Well that's because the `setOnMouseEntered` creates a strange behavior while moving the mouse between menus and the usage of `setOnMouseMoved` fix it.

In addition in case you wondering how did I know to use the `lookup("HBox")` the truth is my first attempt was `System.out.println( menuBar.lookupAll("*"));` which gave me the current informations :

```
[MenuBar@5e57a6ce[styleClass=menu-bar], HBox@13ccf856[styleClass=container], MenuBarSkin$MenuBarButton[id=null, styleClass=menu-button menu]'File', MenuButtonSkinBase$MenuLabeledImpl@25917f7f[styleClass=label]'File', Text[text="File", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=12.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff], StackPane@c341eae[styleClass=arrow-button], StackPane@7b8501c0[styleClass=arrow], MenuBarSkin$MenuBarButton[id=null, styleClass=menu-button menu]'Edit', MenuButtonSkinBase$MenuLabeledImpl@4d8224b7[styleClass=label]'Edit', Text[text="Edit", x=0.0, y=0.0, alignment=LEFT, origin=BASELINE, boundsType=LOGICAL_VERTICAL_CENTER, font=Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=12.0], fontSmoothingType=LCD, fill=0x333333ff], StackPane@3d75fcac[styleClass=arrow-button], StackPane@71f02eed[styleClass=arrow]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for class `javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu` and the method `show(Node anchor, double screenX, double screenY)`

Comment: But I need the context menu to be part of the main window's scene graph.